# Extract a substring that proceeds text enclosed in parenthesizes using R's stringr library

Tags: r, stringr

I'm new to `R` and the `tidyverse` and I'm trying to find the most efficient way to extract a substring from a string that includes parentheses. Sample data and output follows:

```
Jim (Junior)  desired output-> Jim

Kim           desired output-> Kim

Sam (Sr)      desired output-> Sam
```

The parenthesizes were giving me all sorts of trouble I could seem to escape them properly. Strigr what is more performant regular expressions or the `stringr` functions.

Comment: What have you tried? You can escape `(` and `)` in regex with two preceding slashes like `\\(` and `\\)`

Comment: I am sure that there exists some handsome regex answer for this question, but this also works. `data <- c("Jim (Junior)","Kim","Sam (Sr)")` then `gsub(" \\(.*","",data)`

Comment: R studio kept telling me '\('' was missing, but when I used it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using stringr as you want

```
> library(stringr)
> str_remove(string, "\\s*\\(.*\\)")
[1] "Jim" "Kim" "Sam"
```

You can also use R base `sub`

```
> sub("(.*)\\s+\\(.*$", "\\1", string)
[1] "Jim" "Kim" "Sam"
```

where:

```
string <- c("Jim (Junior)", "Kim", "Sam (Sr)")
```

Comment: Your regex is the same as mine

Answer (score 1):

To do this using `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)
input <- c("Jim (Junior)", "Kim", "Sam (Sr)")
output <- str_remove(input, "\\s\\(.*\\)")
```

You can use regular expressions to do this in base R:

```r
input <- c("Jim (Junior)", "Kim", "Sam (Sr)")
output <- sub("\\s\\(.*\\)", "", strings)
```

Comment: your `str_remove` solution is exact the same as mine

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`, suppose your names are in `df$Name`

```
str_extract(df$Name, "[^\\(]*")
```

This says "any `[`character`]` that is not(`^`) `(`, any number of times"

Then, to trim the whitespace, use `trimws`.

```
> df <- data.frame(Name=c("Jim (Junior)", "Kim", "Sam (Sr)"))
> trimws(str_extract(df$Name, "[^\\(]*"))
[1] "Jim" "Kim" "Sam"
```